# Android: How can you specify where in your layout the software keyboard will appear?

Tags: android

Is there a way to specify in your layout which widgets will shift and move when the software keyboard appears?  In some layouts, It will shrink the innermost scrolling area automatically, just making your layout smaller, but there doesn't seem to be a rhyme or reason to when it does this.  How can I tell it which widgets to shrink, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the [`android:windowSoftInputMode`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) attribute in the `<activity>` element in the manifest. Here's an [article](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html) that covers the topic. [Here's a pair of projects](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/InputMethod/) demonstrating the effect of resize vs. "pan-and-scan".

Comment: Thanks, you've helped me yet again :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is related or not, but I have a dialog that whenever the softkeyboard appears, it shrinks my buttons.  The loaded view shows the buttons stretched across the screen, after the edittext is selected, the buttons shrink and are pushed left.

Answer (score 0):

Also useful to know (from [the same article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html) as mentioned above) is that individual window can be configured with its own behavior by `Window.setSoftInputMode(int mode)`.